# Copy a List<HashMap<String, String>> in Java

Tags: java, copy

I'm new in Java. 
I have created a list of `HashMap` and I want to set it in a setter as below:

```
private List<HashMap<String, String>>   parameters = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

public void setParameters(List<HashMap<String, String>> params) {

}
```

Should I loop trough the list? Or I can just do :

```
this.parameters = params;
```

Comment: They have the same type, there is no problem to assign _params_ to _parameters_.

Comment: Thanks you both for the fast answer and  shame on people who give a free -1, we all need to learn, I'm sure that I can teach some things in C to those people..

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but really what's the problem in checking it yourself? It will take you less time to do that than to ask here and wait for an answer. You are expected to try and solve your own problem before asking.

Comment: Maybe my implementation make this harder to test it than ask here I think. But I understand your mind and I agree in the most part of cases.